# Entity Framework (6.0): как сгенерировать базу данных?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

я разбираю простой пример - "Блог", неплохо описанный в MS - овской [документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/new-database)

Но есть проблема.

Все мои попытки воспроизвести описанные действия приводят к ошибкам.

Что я делал:

Я создал новый dotnet core проект типа Console командой

`dotnet new console --use-program-main`

Потом я добавил зависимости:

```
   dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore --version=6.0
   dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --version=6.0
   dotnet add package System.Data.DataSetExtensions
```

Потом я взял код из MS - вского примера, и у меня получился такой пример (полный код):

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

    namespace EfExample;
    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (var db = new BloggingContext()) 
            {
                // Create and save a new Blog
                var blog = new Blog { Name = $"First blog {DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString}" };
                db.Blogs.Add(blog);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
         }
    }

    public class BloggingContext : DbContext 
    {
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Blog {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }
```

При запуске я получаю ошибку `"System.InvalidOperationException: 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContex"`
на строке
`db.Blogs.Add(blog);`

Ага! - сказал я. - Ну конечно, ведь умница EF не знает, к какой базе даанных ему коннектиться!

и я дописал внутрь класса BloggingContext  метод

```
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) 
        {
            options.UseSqlServer("Password=userpassword;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Initial Catalog=Blogs;Data Source=192.168.1.1;TrustServerCertificate=True");
        }
```

с корректной строкой подключения к пустой базе данных.

После этого ошибка изменилась, и стала возникать на строке
`db.SaveChanges();`
и стала она такой:
`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.'`
а внутри еще одна ошибка:
`InnerException   {"Invalid object name 'Blogs'."}`

Вообще, я немного удивлён тем, что у такой классной штуки, как Entity Framework, нет какого то метода типа `.GenerateDB()`,
который просто создаст в базе данных нужную структуру таблиц.

**А как принято это делать, при использовании подхода CodeFirst?**

Спасибо!

Comment: для этих целей есть миграции https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: @ExplodingKitten - Йес! Йес! Спасибо огромное!!